# Why value of second variable is irrelevant after adding space or new line?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm newbie in programming learning C language.I'm little confused right now.I tried to Google about it but can not find out the satisfactory result so i thought to sort out by asking the question in this website.
Have a look at this short program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num1,num2;
    printf("enter the value of num1 and num2:");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
    printf("num1 = %d and num = %d",num1,num2);
    return 0;
}
```

When i enter value **For example- 215-15** without `space` or `new line` than it gives output **num1 = 215** and **num2 = -15** but when i enter `space` or `new line` between **215-** and **15** then it gives output **num1 = 215** and **num2 = -175436266**(or any unexpected number).

I know that when scanf() reads any character which is not in the catagory of conversion specification it put back that character and end processing other inputs.But in the first case `-(minus sign)` seems to be irrelevent input according to the conversion specification but it shows correct output but in the later case it not showing correct output.Why?

Comment: If you check the return value of `scanf`, you will find out that it did not succeed in it's reading, so the variable are not assigned the expected value. So you are getting a junk from them.

Comment: why they are successfully assigned in first case and not in the second ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `215- 15` can only match one number: 215. As soon as `scanf()` reads a `-`, it stops processing the first match since `-` can't possibly be a digit of the current number, so `num1` is matched with 215.

Then, no more numbers can match, because you are left with `- 15`. `scanf()` reads a `-` followed by a space, so there is no valid number to parse, and it returns (after pushing back the space and the dash). It doesn't assign anything to `num2`, so what you see when you print it is garbage.

**So, why does it work with `215-15`?**

The space makes the difference. With `215-15`, `scanf()` again matches the first number with 215, but now you are left with `-15` in the input (rather than `- 15`, as in the earlier example). `-15` doesn't have a space between the sign and the first digit of the number, so `scanf()` sees it as a valid number, and parses it successfully.

In short, in both examples, `-` is interpreted as being the sign of the number for the next match. But `%d` doesn't ignore whitespace characters between the digits of a number, or between the sign and the digits (although it ignores any amount of whitespace *before* the number starts - that is, either before the first digit, or before the sign). So, if it sees a `-` followed by a space, it fails. If it sees a `-` followed by one or more digits, it matches a number successfully, and consumes the digits until a character that is not a digit is found.

Comment: Helpful answer! But please explain why inputting `215-15` works. It is also good to note the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf) about what happens when you use non-whitespace characters that is not a format specific (%).

Comment: `man scanf` states that the whitespace character in format string will match any number of ws including none.

Comment: @OmkarTripathi if you had intialised `num2=0` (say) then `0` would have been printed in the failed example input `215- 15` but since you didn't, `num2` value is still "random" since `scanf` failed, not assigning *any* value.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, a whitespace in the format string causes 0 or more whitespace chars to be consumed. But this happens before the next token begins matching - whitespace is ignored until a non-whitespace char is seen. So, in this case, it stops ignoring whitespace when it sees `-`, at which point it starts parsing the number, until anything that is not a valid digit appears. Since we have a space after `-`, there is really no match.

Comment: still its not clear very much.As John Odom has asked why `215-15` works.

Comment: I guess the question here is why the minus sign right after 215 is not failing the subsequent matching.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening is described in the [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) reference at cplusplus.com.

> Any character that is not either a whitespace character (blank,
>   newline or tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a %
>   character) causes the function to read the next character from the
>   stream, compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches,
>   it is discarded and the function continues with the next character of
>   format. If the character does not match, the function fails, returning
>   and leaving subsequent characters of the stream unread.

Also,

> A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of
>   whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).

The scanf's format string is "%d %d". It expects a number, it throws away whitespace, and another number. After the first number, the '-' character was read did not match the format specifier so scanf failed early, leaving the num2 variable uninitialized.

If you check the return value of scanf, it would fail.

Comment: I'm asking why both values of variables are correct at first and not in second

Comment: In the first case, the '-' can be interpreted as the sign of the second number because it is immediately preceding the number. In the second case, the '-' is not attached to the number and there is a space after it so it cannot be interpreted as a sign. scanf encounters the '-' when it is expecting a number and fails.

Comment: I think the 2nd quote, esp. the "(including none)" part clarifies this.